# Using ffmpeg and aresample with super low sample rate

Tags: ffmpeg, waveform

I am trying to use `ffmpeg` to get data to generate list of peaks with resolution of 30 peaks per second.

the params I'm using are:

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio.wav -filter_complex "[0]aresample=30[resampled]" -map [resampled] output_30.wav
```

which kills almost all information and resulting data array contains only very small values. This waveform is before resampling
[image]

versus after resampling to 60kHz

[image]

My question is if it is possible to use ffmpeg and get maximums (peaks) over each timespan (second or 1/20 second) of audio?

Answer (score 5):

If you want peak data with a 1/20 seconds resolution, use this as the starting point.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -af "aresample=60000,asetnsamples=3000,astats=reset=1:metadata=1,ametadata=print:key='lavfi.astats.Overall.Peak_level':file=stats.log" -f null -
```

The idea is to have a high enough sampling rate using aresample, then divide the audio into equal chunks, each equaling 1/20th of a second, using asetnsamples. Then astats will measure the log the data per-frame (reset=1). Then ametadata will write the value for peak level (in dB) to a text file.

Comment: thank you for the reply, Is there any way to confiture the output to return only numerical peak values and output to pipe? Btw, should I account to number or audio channels somehow? I do not know if audio will be mono or stereo.

Comment: You can output to pipe by setting `file=-`. With to a recent git build, you can add `direct=1` for realtime monitoring. Some metadata like key name and timestamp will be present.